# Set Prepare and execute query in java

Tags: java, mysql

Can I execute following query at once in java using prepareStatement?

```
SET @totalQuestion = (SELECT QuestionVolume FROM rules ORDER BY QuestionVolume DESC LIMIT 1);
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @totalQuestion;
```

Java code that I am thinking about??? (Not sure If I can do something like this?)

```
generateQuestion = getDb().getConnection().prepareStatement(
                "SET @totalQuestion = (SELECT QuestionVolume FROM rules ORDER BY QuestionVolume DESC LIMIT 1);\n"
                + "\n"
                + "PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?';\n"
                + "EXECUTE STMT USING @totalQuestion;");
```

Can anyone explain what is the best why to execute the query in Java?

Update

I changed my statement to the following.

```
 getQuestionRule = getDb().getConnection().prepareStatement(""
                + "SELECT QuestionVolume FROM rules ORDER BY QuestionVolume DESC LIMIT 1", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
 generateQuestion = getDb().getConnection().prepareStatement(
                "SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: these are two statements, they cannot be executed at once, unless they are grouped in a stored procedure.

Comment: I think he can group both sentences in the same transaction to get an atomic operation.

Comment: Yes, but it would still require executing two statements.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Java variable to store `totalQuestion` making your operation atomic through [transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html):

1. Set JDBC auto commmit to false: `con = getDb().getConnection();` `con.setAutoCommit(false);`
2. Execute the first query and load its result into a local variable `totalQuestion = result.getInt("QuestionVolume");`
3. Execute the second query using `totalQuestion` value and not using dynamic sql at mysql level but composing the sql at your program side: `String sql = "SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?";` `PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql); st.setInt(1,totalQuestion); ResultSet res = st.executeQuery();`
4. Set autocommit to true thus commiting your transaction: `con.setAutoCommit(true)`.

Comment: How does `commit` affects a `select` here?

Comment: @Ravinder It frees the transaction.

Comment: My question is, if all are non DML, would it be any affective setting `commit`? And also, OP has not mentioned anything on pooled connections too.

Comment: So basically I need to execute two quires. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Ravinder The first setting to false is used to make sure first and second select queries are executed atomically. I can argue second setting to true may not work and that `con.commit()` should be used.